# Build working libcurl with WinSSL, NTLM, HTTP2, SSH2 and IPv6 support

Tags: php, libcurl, php-curl

In our PHP application, we need the PHP curl-extension built in a way, that it supports the following features:

- WinSSL (Access to the Windows certificate store)
- NTLM, Basic and Digest authentication
- HTTP/2 support
- SSH2 support
- IPv6 support

I've tried to build curl in a way to achieve this:

- Link it against WinSSL
- Link it against nghttp2
- Link it against libssh2
- Enable IPv6

I did so with the command line:

```
nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=dll VC=15 ENABLE_WINSSL=yes DEBUG=no MACHINE=x64 ENABLE_SSPI=no WITH_NGHTTP2=dll WITH_ZLIB=static WITH_SSH2=static WITH_DEVEL=C:\curl\deps-x64
```

In curls `winbuild/` subfolder. Then I compiled the PHP curl extension against the result.

With the result, I have the following **incorrect behavior** when doing an HTTP request against a web service which offers Basic, Digest, NTLM and Negotiate authentication (an Exchange webservice):

- If `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);` is used, everything works fine.
- If `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);` is used, everything works fine, too.
- If `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM | CURLAUTH_BASIC);` is used, **authentication fails**.

The failing request contains an NTLM token which is way too short (seems to be cut off at some point). Some googling indicated that this may be due to curl being compiled to use SSPI. However, I cannot disable SSPI, because WinSSL requires it.

Does anyone know a solution to this? How to get a php-curl extension that fulfills all the above requirements?

Comment: either an auth negotiation issue or a libcurl bug? can you post a CURLOPT_VERBOSE log for `CURLAUTH_NTLM | CURLAUTH_BASIC`  ?

Comment: Why don't you create two compiled version one for NTLM  and another for WinSSL ?

Comment: TFM says you need SSPI to do NTLM on Windows so I don't think that would be it.  Following on @Mason.Chase 's comment, i'd solve it by having wrapper functions and do a doNTLM() || doBasicHTTP() vs. passing the two options to curl.

Comment: @ivanivan The failing call is done by an external library, so we cannot really split NTLM and Basic authentication in our code. As a last resort, we could fork the library and change the code, but that would add additional maintainance overhead to our software. I'd rather have a solution that makes that exact call work :(

Comment: I'm not sure if CURL can do both NTLM and Basic in the same connection so ignoring any SSL, NTLM requires encryption & Base64 encoding before sending it to the server and the server will give Base64 encoded data when you try to connect, this might be your problem try opening a connection first and reading the headers to see what method it needs first basic or NTLM. http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html#ntlmHttpAuthentication

Comment: @MartinBarker: The Server sends multiple, different WWW-Authenticate headers, and curl should choose the appropriate one and do that authentication. The ones curl may choose the appropriate one from are determined by the option from the question, so in the failing case curl should choose either NTLM or Basic auth, and chooses NTLM. But that authentication fails, because the Authorization header generated by curl is broken

Comment: Ok we need to see your code because generally usage of CURL does not get any information from the server before you construct your request.

Comment: It dies - first curl sends the request unauthenticated, gehts a `401 Unauthorized` response with WWW-Authenticate headers, chooses an authentication mechanism depending on the headers from that response and from the configured allowed authentication methods, and then sends the request again, authenticated using the chosen method (NTLM in this case)

Comment: Have you tried `CURLAUTH_ANY`? Would be interesting to see the response headers from the server as well.

Comment: My 2 cents: Do you set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "USER:PWD");`? Would be interesting, if the first auth-negotiation request is then no longer `401`, but authed. Also, if there is forwarding/follow-location involved, then `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, true);` comes into play. All in all, hard to say, without looking at the code or request logs. More info needed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the LibCurl here satisfies all that:

https://curl.haxx.se/windows

Using this file:

```c
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   curl_version_info_data *o = curl_version_info(CURLVERSION_NOW); 
   printf("SSL: %s\n", o->ssl_version);
   printf("NTLM: %d\n", o->features & CURL_VERSION_NTLM);
   printf("HTTP/2: %d\n", o->features & CURL_VERSION_HTTP2);
   printf("SSH2: %s\n", o->libssh_version);
   printf("IPv6: %d\n", o->features & CURL_VERSION_IPV6);
}
```

Build:

```
cc https.c `
'-Icurl-7.70.0-win64-mingw\include' `
'-Lcurl-7.70.0-win64-mingw\lib' `
-lcrypt32 `
-lcurl `
-lwldap32 `
-lws2_32
```

Result:

```
SSL: OpenSSL/1.1.1g (Schannel)
NTLM: 16
HTTP/2: 65536
SSH2: libssh2/1.9.0
IPv6: 1
```

I did not build with Visual Studio, but Clang:

https://github.com/mstorsjo/llvm-mingw

Also I am not sure what exactly `OpenSSL/1.1.1g (Schannel)`, I guess it means OpenSSL and WinSSL both? If that's not the case, you can build LibCurl yourself with `CFG=-winssl`:

https://github.com/nu8/gulf/blob/master/c-https/1-curl.ps1